# Creating a Column from a Specific Value Contained in a Row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame that is formatted like this:

| details | col_1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex1 2019 test | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ex1 2020 review | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| example2 2021 survey | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| row3 2019 data | 4 | 4 | 4 |

I want to create a new column called "Year" appended to the end of this data frame that takes the year value from the row name. I want it to look like this:

| details | col_1 | col2 | col3 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex1 2019 test | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2019 |
| ex1 2020 review | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2020 |
| example2 2021 survey | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2021 |
| row3 2019 data | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2019 |

The row names are unstandardized on purpose to reflect my actual data. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```py
df['Year'] = df.details.str.extract(r'\b(\d{4})\b').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                details  col_1  col2  col3  Year
0         ex1 2019 test      1     1     1  2019
1       ex1 2020 review      2     2     2  2020
2  example2 2021 survey      3     3     3  2021
3        row3 2019 data      4     4     4  2019
```

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi good idea - updated.

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
df['Year'] = df.apply(lambda row: parse(row.details, fuzzy=True).year, axis=1)
```